# Test Pyjnius android api calls without rebuilding apk again and again

Tags: python, android, kivy, pyjnius

I am developing an App with **Kivy** and fortunately **Pyjnius** module is helping me a lot to access the *Android Api(s)* to provide better functionality. But there is one problem, I had to build the apk again and again to test the code on phone because my code uses android Api(s) which is only possible to run on an android device. But rebuilding the apk again and again is too time much consuming. Is there any way out to perform a *hot reload* or *live testing* or something identical to that  which can significantly reduce the time consumption increase efficiency ? ? ?

Answer (score 0):

If you once built a Pyjnius project with

```
buildozer -v debug deploy run
```

and didn't delete the .buildozer folder, building the app should be faster. You do not need to fully build the project when you change the application. You need to rebuild the project if you add some non-standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyjnius playground/tester created by kenekchukwu akubue find him on github by the name kengoon or just google search pyjnius playground